# How can I get a list of all packages used in a webpack bundle?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-3

I need to audit the list of node packages that are used in a webpack bundle. The corresponding webpack config file passes the list of production dependencies (ie the non-dev dependencies from the application's `package.json`) as the list of entry points to `module.exports`. Ideally I'd get a list of all the `package.json` files of every node package that ends up in the bundle. Just searching the `node_modules` directory of the application isn't sufficient as this includes devDependencies, etc.

How can I do this with webpack?

Comment: Would you try  [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer)? May be that you want.